# Random colours from array applied to elements on page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, colors

I have a list of elements, which all need a random background color applied to them from an array of colors.

My HTML structure is simple:

```
<ul class="moreorless-list">
  <li><span>Word</span></li>
  <li><span>Word</span></li>
  <li><span>Word</span></li>
  <li><span>Word</span></li>
  <li><span>Word</span></li>
  <li><span>Word</span></li>
</ul>
```

For example, an array of colors could be: #ffffff, #111111, #222222, #333333 etc.

I need to take the colors from the array and randomly apply them to the list; this of course would mean that some colors are repeated twice is fine.

Any ideas how I could achieve this? PHP or JS is preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('li').each(function () {
    $(this).css('background-color', random());
});

function random() {
    colors = ['red', 'white', 'blue', 'green']
    return colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function get_random_color() {
    function c() {
        return rand_num(256).toString(16);
      }
      return "#"+c()+c()+c();
      }
```

Comment: I have a set of colours I want to use, however. Thanks so far.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a color set use this:

```
$colors = array("#FFFFFF", "#000000", "#333333");
$rand_keys = array_rand($colors);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function getRandomColor(colorArray)
{
   return colorArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*colorArray.length)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd tend to suggest:

```
var options = ['#ffffff', '#111111', '#222222', '#333333'];

function randomColour(el, colours){
    return colours[Math.floor(Math.random()*colours.length)];
}

var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
for (var i = 0, len = spans.length; i<len; i++){
    spans[i].style.backgroundColor = randomColour(this,options);
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/CFGPe/).

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to get a random value out of an array. In PHP, you can achieve this with using `array_rand` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php). One aproach could look something like this:

```
<?php
    function randomColor() {
        $colorArray = array('#ffffff', '#111111', '#222222', '#333333', ...);
        return $colorArray[array_rand($colorArray)]; // array_rand() only returns the key
    }
?>

<ul class="moreorless-list">
    <li style="background-color:<?php echo randomColor(); ?>"><span>Word</span></li>
    <li style="background-color:<?php echo randomColor(); ?>"><span>Word</span></li>
    <li style="background-color:<?php echo randomColor(); ?>"><span>Word</span></li>
    <li style="background-color:<?php echo randomColor(); ?>"><span>Word</span></li>
    <!-- ... -->
</ul>
```